# Android Webview using Fragments to Retain text data across orientation changes

Tags: android, webview, orientation, android-fragments

I need to create a webview with Fragment, so that the data in the webview (text in the forms) are not lost when the orientation changes.

Like in this example [FragmentRetainInstance.Java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.html) I want make webview with setRetainInstance(true) work.

I would be using Android Compatibility Package for Fragments, please help me with an example to achieve the above. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you gonna use Fragment just for that purpose or there are other reasons ??? because, if this is the only reason you can get it done by adding "android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"" as an attribute inside your <activity> tag inside manifest.xml

Comment: Yes Iam doing it just for retaining the data. Losing keyboard for orientation change is not an option for me.

Comment: is there some thing that i'm missing ?? what do mean with losing the keyboard ??? may you see this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 0):

had a very similar problem but had to make a couple of additions to get it to work with various version (including ICS).

In the main app activity I added a slightly different version of what "a fair player" offered.

```
<activity
android:name=".MyMainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

I had this working on pre-Honeycomb with:

```
       <activity
    ....
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
    .... >
```

With fragments and Honeycomb, you need the "screenSize" option on android:configChanges.

Comment: I need a fragments alone solution for retaining data in WebView, I heard it is possible but could get it working yet.
I do not want to use android:configChanges as it is said to leak memory.